# Correct use of JwtTokens in C#

Tags: c#, jwt, claims

I'm playing a with JwtTokens and can't make them work properly.
I'm using http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/ for it.
I know the code is a mess but is just to show what I'm trying to do.
The problem is that I want the JwtTokenHandler to fail the validation because of the lifetime.

```
var key = "5A0AB091-3F84-4EC4-B227-0834FCD8B1B4";
var domain = "http://localhost";
var allowedAudience = "http://localhost";
var signatureAlgorithm = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#hmac-sha256";
var digestAlgorithm = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";
var issuer = "self";
var securityKey = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(key);
var inMemorySymmetricSecurityKey = new InMemorySymmetricSecurityKey(securityKey);

var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
var expiry = now.AddSeconds(1);
var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var claimsList = new List<Claim>()
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "user"),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Webpage, allowedAudience),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Uri, domain),                
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Expiration,expiry.Ticks.ToString())
};
var roles = new List<string>() { "admin" };
claimsList.AddRange(roles.Select(role => new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role)));

var identity = new GenericIdentity("user");

var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
{
    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(identity, claimsList),
    TokenIssuerName = issuer,
    AppliesToAddress = allowedAudience,
    Lifetime = new Lifetime(now, expiry),
    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(inMemorySymmetricSecurityKey, signatureAlgorithm, digestAlgorithm),
};

var token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor));

var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
{
    ValidIssuer = issuer,
    ValidAudience = allowedAudience,
    IssuerSigningToken = new BinarySecretSecurityToken(securityKey)
};

Thread.Sleep(2000);
try
{
    SecurityToken securityToken;
    tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out securityToken);
    Console.WriteLine("OK");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error {0}", e.Message);
}
```

Isn't this suppose to fail since I'm waiting 2 seconds?
It fails if I change the issuer of the ValidationTokenParameter to "x"...

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/fvilers/WebApiOwinIdentityOAuthJwtSample for a correct implementation.

Comment: @FabianVilers the implementation is not complete, the validation which was the isse is throwing an exception.

Answer (score 36):

Found the issue.
The validation parameters have a default clock skew of 5 minutes

```
/// <summary>
/// Default for the clock skew.
/// 
/// </summary>
/// 
/// <remarks>
/// 300 seconds (5 minutes).
/// </remarks>
public static readonly TimeSpan DefaultClockSkew;
```

Setting that to 0 make this work.
Still don't understand why the skew is 5 minutes, if I set the expiry at some point!!!

Comment: @dariogriffo,@Mitklantekutli Actually how did you set that to 0?I tried like this   tokenHandler.Configuration.MaxClockSkew = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0); But not working.

Comment: I set ClockSkew Property in TokenValidationParameters, I dont use configuration. I use code

var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ...
                ClockSkew = new TimeSpan(0)
            };

Comment: @dariogriffo I'd use TimeSpan.Zero for a more succinct approach but that is just splitting hairs! Thanks for this info. Will see if it works for me :)

Comment: @TheSenator you are right, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Just trying and debugging :D

Answer (score 1):

This will definitely works

> TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0) Resets ClockSkew Time to zero

```
TokenValidationParameters parameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
{
  RequireExpirationTime = true,
  ValidateIssuer = false,
  ValidateAudience = false,
  ClockSkew= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0)
};
```