# Is there a minimum expiration time for JwtSecurityToken?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, jwt, token

In token's validation, I checked the token's lifetime and it was **13:07:10**. When I run the validation it was **13:12** and the validation was successful. **Why?**

When it was about **13:15** I run the validation again and it threw an exception, as expected.

Is there a minimum expiration time for the token?

---

Creating the token:

```
var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
    issuer: token_issuer,
    audience: token_audience,
    claims: claims,
    expires: DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(5),                
    signingCredentials: creds
);
```

Validating the token:

```
private static bool ValidateToken(string token)
{
    try
    {
        TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(token_salt),
            ValidAudience = token_audience,
            ValidIssuer = token_issuer,
            RequireExpirationTime = true
        };

        ClaimsPrincipal principal = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ValidateToken(token_last, validationParameters, out SecurityToken validatedToken);

        return true;
    }
    catch(SecurityTokenExpiredException ex)
    {

    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean your second 13:07 in the question to be 13:12?

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry.

Comment: Not a problem - just didn't want anyone else to be confused :)

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but I'm fairly certain, that this will solve the issue - https://stackoverflow.com/a/29456969/6804888

Answer (score 7):

This is due to the [`ClockSkew`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.tokens.tokenvalidationparameters.clockskew?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_IdentityModel_Tokens_TokenValidationParameters_ClockSkew) token validation parameter, which allows one to provide a buffer to account for clock discrepancies between the server issuing the JWT and the one validating it.

In .NET Core / 5+, you can change its value in the `TokenValidationParameters` object in the JwtBearer configuration in Startup as seen below. Its default is 300 seconds, or 5 minutes.

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "https://some-jwt-token-issuer.com";
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                // Set the below to eliminate the skew
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero 
            };
        });
```